# iOS 8 - App not rotating appropriately

Tags: ios, rotation, ios8

I have an app originally developed for iOS 7.1 that I am now testing on an iPad through Xcode 6.1.  When running on an iPad running 7.1 or in the 7.1 simulator the app functions as expected.  On the 8.1 iPad or 8.1 simulator, it appears as though rotation is not handled appropriately.  I see the status bar at the top rotate, but the app itself does not change.  I understand that this is related to rotation methods being deprecated in iOS 8.  My question is...  now what???

I haven't found any documentation that provides a concise answer for how to handle rotation using the new iOS 8 mechanisms.  Is there any way to gracefully handle rotations in iOS 8 the same way I handled them in iOS 7?  I don't even see the old rotation methods being called, so it appears as though this is more than a typical "deprecation".  It seems as though they've eliminated calls to these methods altogether.

Any help or advice?

Comment: I am noticing only the "first" in the list of Supported Orientations for the PList is set, then nothing changes. I rearranged them to ensure it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I fixed it by removing the UIMainStoryboardFile and UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad keys from app's information property list

Give a look to this discussion
https://devforums.apple.com/message/1064397#1064397

Comment: wow, this saved my day (and countless hours of cluelessness)! coded an app without storyboard, all viewcontrollers were created programmatically. Works fine on ALL phones and ipads, ONLY on iPad3 (iOS8.2), the screens did not rotate. removing the single line fixed this. thanks alot, mate!

Answer (score 12):

Are you using storyboards? If so, you may have old code in your `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Try removing the following line of code and any others to do with `UIWindow`:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Others have said to remove lines from your plist file but that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I don't have that line, but I do have a line in which I set the rootViewController on my window.  Necessary, because of how the storyboards need to be loaded.

Comment: Thanks, that was definitely the issue I was having.  Removing that line fixed the problem.

Comment: Wow. What an easy thing to overlook. Thanks ChrisJP.

Comment: What if I use a mix of storyboards and a custom UIWindow?

Answer (score 1):

Use `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` like so:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    // Will rotate

    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        // Will animate rotation
    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        // Did rotate
    }];
}
```

You should take a look at the WWDC 2014 video "View Controller Advancements in iOS 8" where this is discussed.

Comment: I tried adding that to my view controllers, but wasn't seeing it being called.  Is there something else I need to do to enable this?

Comment: @Shadowman Are you using a storyboard? The answer by Fabrice seems to describe rotation issues for apps using storyboards in iOS 8.1. I haven't ran into this problem perhaps because I'm not using storyboards.

Comment: Yes, I am using storyboards.  I will look into his answer.

Comment: Yes,me too using storyboard and have this issue,could anyone help.