# iOS 8 Landscape mode not work properly an Not Rotating app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, landscape-portrait

i am developing app using ios8 support with portrait and Landscape mode both,
but problem is that when i try to rotate my Device to Landscape mode it cant work for me.

i test same thing in my other device iPhone 4 with ios7.1.2 it work fine but not working with ios 8.1 in iphone 4s

please give me suggestion if any one also have the same problem.

```
ARViewController* metaioCloudPlugin = [[ARViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ARViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
self.window.rootViewController = metaioCloudPlugin;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

====
This is my AppDelegate code for main window root view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific, what is failing? It's not rotating? Is not auto-adjusting correctly?

Comment: both, its not rotating and auto-adjusting. some time it give me half black screen and half UI.

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to manage auto-rotate, describe your project structure (UITabbar based? NavControllers? Custom views?) and a picture of the error? Please edit the original question. And again, try to be as specific as possible.

Comment: ARViewController* metaioCloudPlugin = [[ARViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ARViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.window.rootViewController = metaioCloudPlugin;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; ============ This is my code in Appdelegate i am not able to rotate view.

Comment: Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

i fixed this issue .

Remove below line from code and its work fine now.

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

refer this link

[iOS 8 - App not rotating appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553484/ios-8-app-not-rotating-appropriately)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, while I was updating the xib base project for iOS8,

I found the solution inside your question,

thanks for asking :)

```
self.window.rootViewController = loginScreen;
```

While navigating to the screen

```
    loginScreen = [[LoginScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginScreen" bundle:nil];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginScreen];
    self.window            = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = loginScreen;
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```