# Rotating doesn't work correctly when app launches in landscape mode on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, rotation, orientation

I have a trouble with orientation on IPad >ios8.0. 
In Portrait mode all work correctly. But it works wrong when I launch app in landscape mode - http://prntscr.com/72huah

1. launch app in landscape mode.(displayed correctly).
2. Turn to Portrait. (nothing happens).
3. Turn back to landscape

I use xib and in main ViewController:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I fixed this issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553484/ios-8-app-not-rotating-appropriately
This

Answer (score 0):

App Launch image doesn't rotates after view (iOS does not do that). You can add your **UIImageView** and rotate it on the basis of **UIInterfaceOrientation**. After few time you can remove that Launch UIImageView.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
   //Set LandScape Image to UIImageView
      return YES;
}
       //Set Portrait Image to UIImageView 
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I present new view controller on main viewController when Load first page.
[self presentViewController:beforeLoginView animated:false completion:nil]; I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: You can add UIImageView for splash screen for few seconds and after that you can remove that splash and present beforeLoginViewController. You manviewcontroller will rotate so you splash uiimageview will also rotate.

Comment: oh( But Is there any standard solution for this particular problem?

Comment: As i have said in my answer there no other way to achieve this.

Comment: So Why all works correctly when i launch app in portrait mode ?